# Read from string (possible array usage?) C++

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to write alil function here which basically reads from a string. It reads every three characters and evaluates it using the pre-condition (if statement). If conditions are met, it would replace those three letters with new three letters. Then it would output the new string.

I tried writing the code but cant seem to get the logic right. the program runs but it doesn't print out anything. Dont mind the function name and the inaccuracy. I'm just doing a sample function to test this out.

```
string amino_acids(string line)
{
    string acid;
    string acids;
    string newline;
    for( int i= 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        acid = line[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        acids = acid[i];
        if(acids == "GUU")
        {
            acids = "ZAP";  
        }
        newline = acids;
    }
    cout << "Acids: " <<newline <<endl;
    return newline;
}
```

Comment: Your braces are in the wrong places. I think you meant the second `for` loop to be inside the first one, among other things.

Comment: `for( int i= 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    acid = line[i];
}` is equivalent to `if (!line.empty()) acid = line.back();`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: The `if` inside the `for` loop doesn't seem to make any sense. Why would you want to repeat that `if` test 3 times?

Comment: yeah im just confused at my own code lol

Comment: @user2188311, Being confused at your own code is an awfully fun feeling, isn't it? That's what we generally strive to avoid, but coming back to old code especially can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing a `std::string` with the `[]` operator yields a `char`, for which there just happens to be an overloaded `operator=` for strings.

Even if you were looping as I believe you intended (which, as the comments on the question mention, you probably aren't) because acids (which takes the value of a single character) will never be equal to the three character string you're comparing it to.  Thus, no replacements will be performed.

To do what you want, try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i + 3 < line.length(); i += 3) // counting by 3 until end of line
{
    if (line.substr(i, 3) == "GUU")            // if the substring matches
    {
        line.assign("ZAP", i, 3);              // overwrite it with new substring
    }
}
return line;
```

Comment: okay so maybe indexing the string is a bad idea. but isnt there a function that reads a certain amount of characters in a string?

Answer (score 1):

```
for( int i= 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    acid = line[i];
```

Say line contains "abcd", this loop is going to do:

```
acid = 'a';
acid = 'b';
acid = 'c';
acid = 'd';
```

Only the last assignment has any lasting affect.  If you need to actually get three characters from line into acid - you probably want to use `+=` to add characters into `acid`, rather than `=`.  But, if you loop over all of line like this, you'll end up doing `acid = line;`.  I assume you want something more like `acid = line.substr(0, 3)`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
     acids = acid[i];
```

This is going to crash.  `acid` is definitely a single character string, and you're indexing into `acid[1]` and `acid[2]` on the 2nd and 3rd iterations.  While you're learning C++, you should probably use `.at(i)` which will throw an exception when you attempt to use an invalid index - you can catch the exception and at least have some indication of the problem.  As is, it's undefined behaviour.

To use at, you need a `try` / `catch` block... the basic form is:

```
int main()
try
{
    ...your code in here...
    some_string.at(i);
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "caught exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

More generally, try putting some `std::cout` statements throughout your code so you know what values your variables actually have... you would easily have seen that they weren't what you expected.  Alternatively, use an interactive debugger and watch the affect of each statement's execution.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from your description, you want something like so

```
//note below does not compile, its just psuedo-code

string amino_acid(const string& sequence){
  string result = sequence; //make copy of original sequence
  For i = 0 to sequence.length - 3 
    string next3Seq = sequence(i,3); //grab next 3 character from current index
    If next3Seq == 'GUU' //if the next next three sequence is 'GUU'
      then result.replace(i,3,'ZAP'); //replace 'GUU' with 'ZAP'
    EndIf
  EndFor
  return result;   
}
```

You can use that as a start to code. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question. I have written some code. Please look below

```
string acids;
string newLine;
int limit=1;
for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
{
    acids=acids+line[i];
    if(limit==3)//Every 3 characters
    {
      if(acids == "GUU")
        {
            acids = "ZAP";  
        }       
        limit=1;
        acids=""
        newline=newline+acids;
    }
limit++;
    return newline;
}
```